# c++ winapi SHBrowseForFolder browse for hidden folders

Tags: c++, winapi

When I open a dialog box with SHBrowseForFolder, I want it to browse for hidden folders too
(hidden folders appear in the dialog box).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`SHBrowseForFolder` doesn't show hidden folders.  You will need to use a `FolderView` control or create your own browser dialog using `FindFirst/FindNext`.

Comment: Do you know if  the users folder view settings effects `SHBrowseForFolder`?

Comment: yes show / hide files folders will fix it but i dont want the user to have to do it.

Comment: @CareyGregory would you plz explain to me what u mean by FolderView

Comment: FolderView is one of several folder browsing controls available for Windows.  I just used it as an example of alternative ways to browse folders that don't depend on the user's Explorer settings.